# Mirth Connect deployment strategy and failover strategy?

Tags: mirth

I am first time deploying mirth connect on a hospital, we have build the channels and everything with mirth and its working file. but with the deployment strategy I am confused, I mean should I use "Mirth Appliances" or should we deploy it on our own server (we prefer RH linux). the problem with deploying with our own server is that how to build the failover strategy with it. so suggest me about implementing failover strategy with Mirth Connect ?

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using Mirth Appliance . For 2 basic and important reason - First is Mirth support, which will be easily available and secondly Processing of messages is 3x faster on Mirth appliance against Mirth Connect.

[This](http://www.mirthcorp.com/news/mirth-appliance-webinar#vid=3) is a webinar on using Mirth appliance.

For failover strategy you can contact Mirth for that.

Answer (score -1):

I implemented the fail over strategy on with heartbeat and pacemaker, although I had to modify the mcservice script as it was not LSB compatible and did a lot of hard work on other peaces. But at the end its working fine.

Comment: Hi kavi, i am also thinking about implementing your scenario for one of my customers. Would you be so kind to share the details on all your hard work? i would pay you a beer :)